# multiple Hadamard gates

Tags: hadamard

[image]query in when we apply multiple H gates in multiple qubits.
suppose, one circuit,
qreg_q = QuantumRegister(2, 'q')
creg_c = ClassicalRegister(2, 'c')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qreg_q, creg_c)

circuit.h(qreg_q[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwC5x.png))
circuit.h(qreg_q[0])
circuit.h(qreg_q[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwC5x.png))
gives output for '00' and '01' states.
and
[image]
qreg_q = QuantumRegister(2, 'q')
creg_c = ClassicalRegister(2, 'c')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qreg_q, creg_c)

circuit.h(qreg_q[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwC5x.png))
circuit.h(qreg_q[0])
circuit.h(qreg_q[0])
gives output for '00' and '10' states.

How to do this internal calculation? anyone help plz... how to derive.. for more H gates..

Comment: Can you draw a circuit for what you're trying to implement? Then use a circuit identity where you can replace two H gates on the same wire with a blank wire.

Comment: how to post a picture in comment?

Comment: yes i know that but i am just looking for the detailed calculations in these two different cases?

Comment: You can't post a picture in a comment, but you can post it in the question (and improve the question in doing so).

Comment: I did. if possible kindly explain.

Answer (score 1):

You start by using the identity $H^2=I$. So, take your first circuit. You do Hadamard on the top qubit, and nothing on the second qubit or the classical bit. Thus, your output would be
$$
(H|0\rangle)\otimes |0\rangle=(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)\otimes|0\rangle/\sqrt{2}=(|00\rangle+|10\rangle)/\sqrt{2}
$$
So, you can see how the outputs should be 00 and 10 with 50:50 probability.

This, however, was using the convention that assume the top qubit in the circuit is the first qubit in the tensor product. This is the convention that you'll find in pretty much any quantum computation textbook. However, it's not the convention that qiskit uses, which is where I assume you're performing these calculations. They take the tensor product in the *opposite* order, so the top qubit is the last one in the tensor product. Thus, the outputs are 00 and 01 with 50:50 probability.

Comment: But for teh first circuit it is '00' and '01' and fr the second '00' and '10'..

Comment: ok.. got it now..